# Django - testing view which works with ajax requests

Tags: django, django-unittest

I want to test that my view returns correct json after processes. here is my view:

```
@login_required
@require_POST
def xxx_view(request):
    if 'post_id' in request.POST:
        post_id = request.POST['post_id']

        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        post.order = 2
        post.save()

        json_dump = simplejson.dumps({'new_title': post.order,})
        return HttpResponse(json_dump, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('oups')
```

this works correctly. Here is what i ve tried for testing:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.utils import simplejson
from app.models import *

c = Client()
class CustomTests(TestCase):
    def test_xxx(self):
        json_data = simplejson.dumps({'post_id': 1,})

        response = client.post('/content/vote/', json_data,
                content_type='application/json',
                HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) # this is OK.
        self.assertEqual(response.content, 2) # but this fails.
```

response.content returns empty string.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your second assertion. `response.content` would be something like `{"new_title": 2}`, surely?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Probably. But it returns empty string ''

Comment: Why is your view returing a `302`? It doesn't look like you are issueing one?

Comment: @dm03514 i dont know that exactly . this is not the only one returns 302 in my views.

Comment: I am not logged in while testing this views. may this cause that 302 status code? @dm03514

Comment: yes that is the reason, make sure you create a test user and use the test client helper to login the user first https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.client.Client.login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `login_required` decorator is redirecting your unauthenticated user.  Make sure you create a test user and log that user in using test client `login` method

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.client.Client.login

Answer (score 6):

> **If you are testing it using django.test module.**

Django has a really handy function on the request object that will determine if the request was an AJAX request (an XMLHttpRequest):

[`request.is_ajax()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax)

It simply checks whether the X-REQUESTED_WITH header is equal to 'XMLHttpRequest', a standard that's supported by most javascript libraries.

```
from django.test.client import Client
client = Client()
client.post("http://example.com", {"foo": "bar"}, **{'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 
'XMLHttpRequest'})
```

Please note that `is_ajax` is deprecated in Django 3.1, and will be removed from Django at a later version.

Comment: Note that the `X-Requested-With` header is not added by default by the browser when using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, it's something that client-side libraries like JQuery add.

Answer (score 3):

When the response code is 302 you are dealing with a redirect. Redirects have their own object assigned to them, and their .content property is empty. If you want to follow the redirect you can add follow=True to the client.post, if you want to check the redirect location you can check response["Location"].

Answer (score 0):

You can now do the following:

```
client.post("http://example.com", {"foo": "bar"}, xhr=True)
```